# Render an image widget before showing on screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

My app has a list of pages you can swipe between. These pages include network images. The problem is, the network images are fetched and built only when they are visible, meaning the user watches the whole process happen.

I understand this is the intentional functionality of flutter for efficiency, but I am looking for a way to fetch, load and cache a page (that contains network images) before the user navigates to it.

[Now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F27xH.gif)

[Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNQcy.gif)

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/precacheImage.html

Answer (score -1):

In your pubspec.yaml file,

Add this as a dependency

```
meet_network_image:^0.1.2
```

In your dart file, where you want the image to be, place this line of code

```
MeetNetworkImage(
                  imageUrl:
                      "Your image url.jpg",
                  loadingBuilder: (context) => Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      ),
                  errorBuilder: (context, e) => Center(
                        child: Text('Error appear!'),
                      ),
                ),
```

Comment: Please upvote and mark as the answer, if this helped you.

Comment: What does meet network image do? does it cache it or preload it?

Comment: @HenryAndersen did you see my comment below your question?

Comment: @pskink yes thank you. I just now finished implementing precaching the images. I know the images are being precached (through print statements), but theres still a sizable delay when I render the images (~1s). Whereas the text is there instantly. Is this normal for precached images, and is there any way around it? I can upload a gif of the delay if you would like. Maybe fetching images from the cache just takes this long.

Comment: @pskink https://imgur.com/a/bmhDbFL here's the behavior now, I would would like to avoid any images popping out of nowhere if possible. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -1):

just use [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) package like this:

```
CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: "image path",
        placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
     ),
```

Comment: I am doing this but my problem is that this cached netwrok image widget only builds when Its on the screen. So Im still stuck loading it when the user sees it.

Comment: True, but only the first time, the image will be stored in the cache and you will be able to view it without the device being connected to the Internet, Don't forget to test the app on Release Mode, performance will vary greatly